# bash scripting tput getting errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, tput

I need to figure out what is wrong with this tput menu.

```
#!/bin/bash

tput setb 3
tput clear

function main_menu 
{
option=0
until [ "$option" = "4" ]; do
echo "  1.) Monitor existing processes "
echo "  2.) Copy passwd to /home directory "
echo "  3.) Ping local host "
echo "  4.) Exit "

echo -n "Enter choice:"
read option
echo ""
case $option in

    1 ) ps aux;echo "The list has been successfully generated!";
    2 ) cp /etc/passwd /home;echo "The passwd file has been copied to your home directory.";
    3 ) ping -c 4 127.0.0.1;echo "You have completed pinging localhost" );
    4 ) exit;; 
    * ) tput setf 4;echo "Please enter between number 1 and 4";tput setf 4;

esac
done
 }
```

I've made it in the If/Then statement, and that works but I am trying to learn on using tput.

if/then ( is working)
    #!/bin/bash
    clear
    echo "Main Menu "
    echo "1. Monitor existing processes "
    echo "2. Copy passwd to /home directory "
    echo "3. Ping local host "
    echo "4. Exit "

```
read num 

if [ $num -eq 1 ]   
then ps aux
        echo "The list has been successfully generated! "

elif [ "$num" -eq 2 ]
then cp /etc/passwd /home
        echo "The passwd file has been copied to your home directory."

elif [ "$num" -eq 3 ]
then ping -c 4 127.0.0.1
        echo "You have completed pinging localhost"

elif [ "$num" -eq 4 ]
then clear

fi
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Not sure if this of value to you but when writing/learning I use bash -x nameofscript.sh. This should help debug the issue.

Comment: @cremfraiche sorry if it doesn't make sense. I am a beginner to bash scripting. I'm trying to accomplish same task as in 2nd script with tput from the first script. For some reason I am unable to get it to work.

Comment: @user510209 thanks for the tip. I'm stuck in one of the assignments from linux class.

Comment: I gave you a working solution, however the problem was not in your tput usage, but other syntax errors throughout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

tput setb 3         # if you set these inside the loop, you won't have to mess with color as much later on.
tput clear

function main_menu     # this can be done a better way. slightly incorrect syntax as-is. also, you define main_menu but never call the function.
{
option=0       # not neded
until [ "$option" = "4" ]; do    # quotes not needed
echo "  1.) Monitor existing processes "       # this can all be cleaned up
echo "  2.) Copy passwd to /home directory "
echo "  3.) Ping local host "
echo "  4.) Exit "

echo -n "Enter choice:"
read option    # the echo prompt and read can be shortened with read -p
echo ""        # quotes not needed
case $option in

    1 ) ps aux;echo "The list has been successfully generated!";     # all of the case entries need to end in double semi-colons
    2 ) cp /etc/passwd /home;echo "The passwd file has been copied to your home directory.";
    3 ) ping -c 4 127.0.0.1;echo "You have completed pinging localhost" );   # there is an unnecessary ")" here 
    4 ) exit;; 
    * ) tput setf 4;echo "Please enter between number 1 and 4";tput setf 4;   # I think you might be trying to set the warning red, but both of your tput commands set color to red.
esac
done
 }
```

I offer a similar and functional way to do this (with some other colors as well):

```
#!/bin/bash

tput clear

main_menu()
{
until [ $option = 4 ]; do
tput setb 2
tput setf 5
read -p "  
1.) Monitor existing processes
2.) Copy /etc/passwd to /home directory
3.) Ping local host
4.) Exit
Enter choice: " option
echo 
case $option in

    1) ps aux;echo "The list has been successfully generated!";;
    2) cp /etc/passwd /home;echo "The passwd file has been copied to your home directory.";;
    3) ping -c 4 127.0.0.1;echo "You have completed pinging localhost" ;;
    4) exit;; 
    *) tput setf 4; echo "Please enter between number 1 and 4\n\n";;

esac
done
}

main_menu
```

**The three main issues:**

- Your function syntax is slightly off. There are [three ways](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) to declare functions, IMO the way I have shown is the cleanest and simplest way.
- The very important **;;** at the end of lines in case statements
- And not having your default colors inside the loop. This one wouldn't break the script, but it makes what you are trying to accomplish with the error text easier.

Comment: wow thanks for your help, I've been slamming my head trying to figure out how to make it work. I made it work by using if/then but not this way. This looks much cleaner and nicer. Time to learn this way. Thanks again. This is a great community with knowledgable people.

Comment: @Hp88 You are very welcome, I hope this helps you learn some new techniques. If my answer works for you, please select it as the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: @Hp88 Also, please be aware when I first posted this answer there was an accidental space before the last bracket that would give an error. I have edited the answer to remove it.

Comment: `until [ option` should be `until [ "$option"`

Comment: **Bash** is not **python** so `"""` do not make a sense: one `"` is enough as `""` mean *nothing*

Comment: @Costas option does not require **$** here because there is nothing to expand. Thanks for spotting the triple block quotes, force of habit, answer has been adjusted.

Comment: You are wrong. Try `option=4;until [ option = 4 ] ; do echo Inside ; break ; done` and `option=4;until [ $option = 4 ] ; do echo Inside ; break ; done`

Comment: You are right, thank you for the visual example.

Answer (score 0):

first off you need to correct a couple of minor errors in the basic code.

- each case statement needs to be terminated with **two** semicolons ;;
- Option 3 has an unnecessary parenthesis towards the end which must be removed
- The whole of the script, as presented, is defined in the function main_menu but this function is never called. Add a separate line containing just the text **main_menu** which will execute the code in the function.

if the tput color statements don't work try using setab and set setaf. The difference is that setb and setf support only 8 colors while setab, setaf support 256 colors. Depends on your terminal, These changes work fine for me in mate-terminal.